# Using Turbolinks to act a little like an SPA?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pjax, turbolinks

I was reading about Turbolinks in ROR and I started wondering, as Turbolinks basically acts like 'pjax' to issue a 'GET' request from the server, while Tubolinks replaces the contents of the entire body.

I was wondering if say, I have a chat box in my page. Can I target the turbolinks so that just the Chat Div or a specific id does not change while the other parts of the body change? In this way, the chat can always be alive even when I transition to other pages without refreshing and reconnecting each time? In this way, wont the application behave in a kind of SPA?

Is what I said possible? If yes, then how?

Comment: When you issue a GET request the entire target gets replaced. So, in order to have a portion of your page unaltered you should keep it out of target. As verbose as it may look, you should replace the content of each portion of the page separately.

Comment: So is the best way to NOT use Turbolinks and use Pjax instead and target the divs accordingly?

Comment: If your app is all about this chat box and you can wrap everything else (in the body) in one div, then you probably need only pjax call.

Answer (score 1):

This functionality was recently included in the Turbolinks v3.0 [Official GitHub repo](https://github.com/rails/turbolinks)